# DIsplaying Date in custom format -Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

What's the best way to display current date on flutter using the following format example :

October 25,Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definetely

```dart
 DateFormat('MMMM d,EEEE').format(DateTime.now())
```

But make sure you also import the following

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```